# Weird unintentional rounding

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have an object `value`:

```
var myThingy = {
   value: 10,
}
```

When I add/subtract complex integers (such as something with `Math.PI`) to `value`, it gets rounded (see snippet)! Why is this? What can I do to no get `value` rounded?

```js
var myThingy = {
  value: 10, 
}
document.write(myThingy.value + "<p>"); 
myThingy.value--; 

document.write(myThingy.value + "<p>"); 
myThingy.value - (45 / 360) * ( 2 * (Math.PI)); 

document.write(myThingy.value);
```

Comment: "complex"... "integers"... `Math.PI`. Hm. Odd. I have no idea what could possibly be going wrong...

Comment: In the line `myThingy - (45 / 360) * ( 2 * (Math.PI));` a) you're not reassigning `myThing.value` so obviously `9` is logged again b) you're using an object where a number is expected c) no rounding but standard floating point rounding is going on?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't being rounded (at least, not back to an integer).

You've written an expression which **reads** the `value` of `myThingy` (although you actually want its `value` property), but you aren't doing anything with the result of evaluating that expression.

You need to assign the result back to the property before you look at it.

```js
var myThingy = {
  value: 10, 
}
document.write(myThingy.value + "<p>"); 
myThingy.value--; 

document.write(myThingy.value + "<p>"); 
myThingy.value = myThingy.value - (45 / 360) * ( 2 * (Math.PI)); 

document.write(myThingy.value);
```

Comment: Oh no, it rounds Math.PI to about 15 digits!

Answer (score 1):

```
myThingy - (45 / 360) * ( 2 * (Math.PI));
```

There is no `=` in this line. You are not re-assigning the result to myThingy in any way. Which is good, because you're attempting to subtract a number from an object.

So basically: pay attention to what you are doing, and to what each variable holds. It helps to give your variables meaningful names in this regard.

Comment: `myThingy` should be `myThingy.value`.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake Yes it should, but that's not what you wrote in your question originally, which is where I copy-pasted the line from to show you what was wrong.

Comment: Sure, but never attempted to subtract a number from an object. Might be confusing now that this answer and my question says different things, but whatevz.